# EF inserting values in table failed after some time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, savechanges

I am working on `EF`. I am trying to insert into a table, the insert function is in a thread.

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytes = port.BytesToRead;
    //string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

    Thread.Sleep(50);

    try
    {
        receivedBytes = port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }

    var receiveData = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
    var finalData = receiveData.Replace("-", "");
    //Thread.Sleep(100);

    Console.WriteLine("Thread Going to Start");

    new Thread(() => {
            SaveData(finalData);
        }).Start(); // starting the thread

    port.DiscardOutBuffer(); 
    port.DiscardInBuffer();
}
```

And this is my save data function

```
public void SaveData(string finalData)
{
    Console.WriteLine(LineNumber() + "Data Transmiting...");
    thread = Thread.CurrentThread;         


mdc_dbEntities e = new mdc_dbEntities();

            var msn = e.mdc_meter_config.Where(m => m.m_hex == sr).Select(s => new { s.msn, s.p_id, s.meter_id }).ToList();

    var H = finalData.Substring(0, 2);

    using (mdc_dbEntities u = new mdc_dbEntities())
    {
        foreach (var res in msn)
        {
            var cust_id = e.mdc_meter_cust_rel.Where(m => m.msn == res.msn)
                                              .Select(s => s.cust_id)
                                              .FirstOrDefault();

            mdc_meters_data data = new mdc_meters_data()
                    {
                        msn = res.msn,
                        cust_id = cust_id,
                        device_id = res.meter_id.ToString(),
                        kwh = e_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p1 = a_vol_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p2 = b_vol_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p3 = c_vol_val.ToString(),
                        current_p1 = a_curr_val.ToString(),
                        current_p2 = b_curr_val.ToString(),
                        current_p3 = c_curr_val.ToString(),
                        data_date_time = Convert.ToDateTime(theDate.ToString(format)),
                        d_type = d_type.ToString(),
                        pf1 = a_pf_val.ToString(),
                        pf2 = b_pf_val.ToString(),
                        pf3 = c_pf_val.ToString(),
                        p_id = res.p_id,
                    };
            u.mdc_meters_data.Add(data);
        }

        u.SaveChanges();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(LineNumber() + "Data Saved");
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}

try
{
    thread.Abort(); // aborting it after insertion
    //Thread.Sleep(50);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
}
}
```

The above code runs for some time, but after that I encountered an error at `u.SaveChanges();`

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'An error occurred while closing the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
>   MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
>   MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed.
>
> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I have looked into each solution and tried them but still unable to resolve this issue. I must be missing something that I don't know.

**Update 1 My whole code**

**Calling constructor**

```
  public CommunicationEngine()
    {
        port.ReadTimeout = 500;
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        port.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Port opened successfully");

        Console.WriteLine("I am Recieving");
    }
```

**Calling handler**

```
 private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        int bytes = port.BytesToRead;


        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes are ok..." + port.BytesToRead + " Recieved ");
        try
        {
            receivedBytes = port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }


        var receiveData = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
        var finalData = receiveData.Replace("-", "");
        //Thread.Sleep(100);

        Console.WriteLine("Thread Going to Start");

        try
        {
            new Thread(() => {
                SaveData(finalData);
            }).Start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }          


        port.DiscardOutBuffer(); port.DiscardInBuffer();



    }
```

**Saving data into DB**

```
public void SaveData(string finalData)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(LineNumber() + "Data Transmiting...");
        thread = Thread.CurrentThread;

        if (finalData.Length == 138)
        {
            comm = true;

            var H = finalData.Substring(0, 2);

            var FC = finalData.Substring(2, 9);

            var len = finalData.Substring(10, 2);

            var sr = finalData.Substring(12, 12);

            var energy_tag = finalData.Substring(24, 4);

            var e_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(28, 8)) / 10;

            var a_curr_tag = finalData.Substring(36, 4);

            var a_curr_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(40, 8)) / 1000;

            var b_curr_tag = finalData.Substring(48, 4);

            var b_curr_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(52, 8)) / 1000;

            var c_curr_tag = finalData.Substring(60, 4);

            var c_curr_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(64, 8)) / 1000;

            var a_vol_tag = finalData.Substring(72, 4);

            var a_vol_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(76, 8)) / 10;

            var b_vol_tag = finalData.Substring(84, 4);

            var b_vol_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(88, 8)) / 10;

            var c_vol_tag = finalData.Substring(96, 4);

            var c_vol_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(100, 8)) / 10;

            var a_pf_tag = finalData.Substring(108, 4);

            var a_pf_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(112, 4)) / 1000;

            var b_pf_tag = finalData.Substring(116, 4);

            var b_pf_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(120, 4)) / 1000;

            var c_pf_tag = finalData.Substring(124, 4);

            var c_pf_val = hexToDec(finalData.Substring(128, 4)) / 1000;

            var crc = finalData.Substring(132, 4);

            var ftr = finalData.Substring(136, 2);


            var d_type = "600";

            DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;

            string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
            Console.WriteLine(LineNumber() + "Data Ready to be inserted in DB");
            using (mdc_dbEntities u = new mdc_dbEntities())
            {
                var msnList = u.mdc_meter_config.Where(m => m.m_hex == sr)
                .Select(s => new { s.msn, s.p_id, s.meter_id })
                .ToList();

                foreach (var res in msnList)
                {
                    var cust_id = u.mdc_meter_cust_rel.Where(m => m.msn == res.msn)
                        .Select(s => s.cust_id)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    mdc_meters_data data = new mdc_meters_data()
                    {
                        msn = res.msn,
                        cust_id = cust_id,
                        device_id = res.meter_id.ToString(),
                        kwh = e_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p1 = a_vol_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p2 = b_vol_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p3 = c_vol_val.ToString(),
                        current_p1 = a_curr_val.ToString(),
                        current_p2 = b_curr_val.ToString(),
                        current_p3 = c_curr_val.ToString(),
                        data_date_time = Convert.ToDateTime(theDate.ToString(format)),
                        d_type = d_type.ToString(),
                        pf1 = a_pf_val.ToString(),
                        pf2 = b_pf_val.ToString(),
                        pf3 = c_pf_val.ToString(),
                        p_id = res.p_id,
                    };
                    u.mdc_meters_data.Add(data);

                }
                try
                {
                    u.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }

            }                

            Console.WriteLine(LineNumber() + "Data Saved");
            Thread.Sleep(50);

        }
        else if(finalData.Length == 30)
        {
            var msn_no = finalData.Substring(12, 12);

            mdc_dbEntities p = new mdc_dbEntities();

            var update = p.meter_control.Where(c => (c.comm_executed == 0))
                          .Where(o => (o.m_hex == msn_no))
                          .SingleOrDefault();

            if(update.comm_sent == "Disconnect")
            {
                update.comm_executed = 1;
                update.comm = 0;
                p.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Meter Disconnected....");
            }
            else if(update.comm_sent == "Connect")
            {

                update.comm_executed = 1;
                update.comm = 1;
                p.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Meter Connected....");
            }             

            comm = true;
        }
        else
        {
            comm = true;
        }

        try
        {
            thread.Abort();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `var cust_id = e.mdc_meter_cust_rel.Where(m => m.msn == res.msn)                                              .Select(s => s.cust_id).FirstOrDefault();` what is e

Comment: what is `msn` and what is its count typically

Comment: @Seabizkit `msn` is the serial number. `e` is the object of my `dbcontext`. `mdc_dbEntities e = new mdc_dbEntities();
                
                var msn = e.mdc_meter_config.Where(m => m.m_hex == sr).Select(s => new { s.msn, s.p_id, s.meter_id }).ToList();`

Comment: Unlike `u`, which is created with a `using` block, I don't see any code to get rid of `mdc_dbEntities e = new mdc_dbEntities();`. So I suspect you pile up more opened connections until the server or client is not accepting any more. But I would also recommend to re-think the Thread based approach. You would probably be better of working with `Task` instead.

Comment: The context `e` should close its connection after reading. Still, it's better to wrap it in a `using`. But why do you create two contexts of the same type? That's not necessary. That said, the external variables `port` and `receivedBytes` indicate that this can't be thread-safe code if these objects aren't thread-safe. Most likely, they aren't. I'd start making your code thread-safe, which is easier when refactoring it to async-await syntax. Then it's also easier to debug this.

Comment: look closely u are using `e` where u should be using 'u' `e.mdc_meter_cust_rel.Where(m => m.msn == res.msn)`

Comment: Don't abort threads.

Comment: My guess is that the connection to your DB host is getting closed abruptly, EF tries to reuse it because it hasn't been informed of the connection closing, sends a request and it times out. That usually happens if between you and your db provider there is a proxy/firewall not correctly configured. If that's the case the best you can do is to protect your function with try/catch, force the connection to be closed using `dbContext.Connection.Close();` and retry the operation with a new context to ensure it creates a new connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing EF related changes in a manually initiated thread is not a good idea. Try to run the EF changes in the same thread. If you are bothered with processing incoming requests, use Async, and Await feature. I have modified your code to accommodate this feature. Please try this.

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytes = port.BytesToRead;
    //string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

    try
    {
        receivedBytes = port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }

    var receiveData = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
    var finalData = receiveData.Replace("-", "");

    Console.WriteLine("Thread Going to Start");

    SaveDataAsync(finalData).Wait(); // this call will become sync and runs under main thread.

    port.DiscardOutBuffer(); 
    port.DiscardInBuffer();
}
```

```
public async Task<bool> SaveDataAsync(string finalData)
{
mdc_dbEntities e = new mdc_dbEntities();

            var msn = e.mdc_meter_config.Where(m => m.m_hex == sr).Select(s => new { s.msn, s.p_id, s.meter_id }).ToList();

    var H = finalData.Substring(0, 2);
var isSaveSuccess = false;
    using (mdc_dbEntities u = new mdc_dbEntities())
    {
        foreach (var res in msn)
        {
            var cust_id = e.mdc_meter_cust_rel.Where(m => m.msn == res.msn)
                                              .Select(s => s.cust_id)
                                              .FirstOrDefault();

            mdc_meters_data data = new mdc_meters_data()
                    {
                        msn = res.msn,
                        cust_id = cust_id,
                        device_id = res.meter_id.ToString(),
                        kwh = e_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p1 = a_vol_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p2 = b_vol_val.ToString(),
                        voltage_p3 = c_vol_val.ToString(),
                        current_p1 = a_curr_val.ToString(),
                        current_p2 = b_curr_val.ToString(),
                        current_p3 = c_curr_val.ToString(),
                        data_date_time = Convert.ToDateTime(theDate.ToString(format)),
                        d_type = d_type.ToString(),
                        pf1 = a_pf_val.ToString(),
                        pf2 = b_pf_val.ToString(),
                        pf3 = c_pf_val.ToString(),
                        p_id = res.p_id,
                    };
            u.mdc_meters_data.Add(data);
        }

       isSaveSuccess = (await u.SaveChangesAsync())>0; // if records inserted, the count will be more than 0
    }

   return isSaveSuccess;
}

}
```

Comment: @Faisal - Did you try this? were you able to succeed?

Comment: I am calling `DataReceivedHandler` like this `port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);` and it's giving me error `'Task CommunicationEngine.DataReceivedHandler(object, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)' has the wrong return`

Comment: @Faisal - I updated the answer. made the call SaveDataAsync(finalData).Wait() to sync so that the signature of the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler won't change. Please try now

Comment: I have also tried your updated code. Now I am not getting full bytes returned. In this case data is not saving into database

Comment: I have added my whole code (the original one). Kindly see it.

Comment: @Faisal - If you are debugging your code, which IF condition is hit? Also, wherever you have "SaveChanges()" assign it to a variable like var saveCount = SaveChanges(); and debug the code. if the variable is having count as 0, then most likely the tracking of entities is not happening. I will simplify your code and let you know. Meanwhile, try this and share your update

Comment: It's not going in last else part :(

Comment: @Faisal - what is finalData.length? based on this value it goes to IF or ELSEIF or ELSE part. what is the value of "update.comm_sent" ? if you are talking about last else part, that means finalData.Length is not 138 and 30. So there won't be anything to add and save it in DB. If my understanding is incorrect, you need to be clear in explaining which line of your code is executed and what is expected to execute?

Comment: Yes It's neither 138 nor 30. The error I am telling is coming under 1st if condition `if(finalData.length == 138)`

Answer (score 0):

this is easier to read and may help

saying all this please ensure that you can actually make a connection to the db
double check connectionString

```
public void SaveData(string finalData)
{
    Console.WriteLine(LineNumber() + "Data Transmiting...");

    using (mdc_dbEntities dbContext = new mdc_dbEntities())
    {
        var msnList = dbContext.mdc_meter_config.Where(m => m.m_hex == sr)
                    .Select(s => new { s.msn, s.p_id, s.meter_id })
                    .ToList();

        //put debug point here and check that msnList is populated
        foreach (var item in msnList)
        {
            //this is slow as it will be a db query for each loop
            var cust_id = dbContext.mdc_meter_cust_rel.Where(m => m.msn == item.msn)
                                   .Select(s => s.cust_id)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

            var data = new mdc_meters_data()
            {
                msn = item.msn,
                cust_id = cust_id,
                device_id = item.meter_id.ToString(),
                kwh = e_val.ToString(),
                voltage_p1 = a_vol_val.ToString(),
                voltage_p2 = b_vol_val.ToString(),
                voltage_p3 = c_vol_val.ToString(),
                current_p1 = a_curr_val.ToString(),
                current_p2 = b_curr_val.ToString(),
                current_p3 = c_curr_val.ToString(),
                data_date_time = Convert.ToDateTime(theDate.ToString(format)),
                d_type = d_type.ToString(),
                pf1 = a_pf_val.ToString(),
                pf2 = b_pf_val.ToString(),
                pf3 = c_pf_val.ToString(),
                p_id = item.p_id,
            };
            dbContext.mdc_meters_data.Add(data);
        }

        //depending on how many you added this may take some time.
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried but still getting same issue

Comment: so you using the above code and get that error? are you sure!! please double check @Faisal

Comment: do it on the same thread and see if you get the issue, remove  `new Thread(() => {` and `        }).Start(); // starting the thread`

Comment: what more interesting is u pass `string finalData)` into a method and then don't even use it